# How to just migrate posts/pages from one site to another?

Tags: migration

I use WP Migrate DB (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to sometimes migrate a DB. Now I just want to migrate the posts from one site to another.

Is this the right way?
- migrate wp_posts
- migrate wp_postmeta

It should only get those entries in wp_posts with post_type = post?

That's all? For pages I do the same, but I select post_type = pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use WordPress export option and after that use import on the second site

[How to Export and Import a Wordpress Blog](http://www.wikihow.com/Export-and-Import-a-Wordpress-Blog)

Comment: Yeah I did that, but some pictures have not been transferred. :/ Especially the ones which are set up as the posts picture.

Comment: @Torben the `featured image` depends on theme support. Maybe thats the problem? 

Another possible cause is that post thumbnails are generated when media uploaded, and might not match up with the current theme`s settings. To fix that you can use the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

It is not simple, nor hard task. You need to know:

## ===1) For migrating entries ===

It is not enough to export `wp_posts` and `wp_post_meta` tables.  Posts are linked to categories (wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_term_relationship tables..). So, at least (if it is pure Wordpress install, without any extra plugins and functionalities), to migrate those 5 tables.   (for **pages**, it is somehow simpler - only wp_posts is enough, using post_type=>pages.)

## ===2) For migrating attachments ===

If you want to migrate pictures/attachments too, then you have to copy contents from `/wp-content/uploads` to target site (be careful not to overwrite some files in target site, in case there already exists same name files).

## ===3)  database correction ! ===

you should replace paths and strings ACCURATELY:

a) for example, if old path is '/home/user385247/public_html` , you should replace that with Target site's path.

b) you should replace `oldsite.com` with `newsite.com`...

You'd better to use tools like this:  https://itask.software/tools/wordpress-migrator

## === Summary ===

Wordpress built-in option is good for automatization, but (in case it matters to you): 
- Bad side:  **It doesnt keep** the same ID's of posts from old site.
- Good side: It automatically tries to import images too. (however, dont know it if do 100% accurately in some cases.. However, try it).

p.s. You can also  search for 3rd party plugins to do this PARTIAL migration (if any exists).

**NOTE, ALWAYS MAKE BACKUP before doing such things.**